# Django: Overriding form save?

Tags: django, forms

Is there any documentation on this? I couldn't dig any up.

I have a custom `ModelForm` for creating articles. Whenever I use this form, I pass in an `article` instance so that I can automatically set the author:

```
    article = Article(author=req.user)
    form = ArticleForm(req.POST, instance=article)
```

How do I access this `instance`/`article` variable from inside `form.save()`?
Is there anything else I need to be aware of when writing this method? Or does it just need to return an `article` and that's pretty much it?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817284/overriding-the-save-method-in-django-modelform

Comment: I guess the answer I'm looking for is: `article = super(ArticleForm, self).save(commit=False)`.

Comment: Post the answer and accept it... it'll help everyone else, and give you a badge probably :)

Comment: Ok... I'll accept it after the mandatory 2 day waiting period, but in the meantime, is there a way to check if `save()` is updating an existing article, or creating a new one?

Comment: @mark it creates a new one unless you pass an instance. if you pass an instance, it does an update

Comment: @Jim: Yes... but how do I check which case it is inside the `save()` method? Is checking if `article.id` is set a reliable method?

Comment: You could use: article, created = Article.objects.get_or_create(whatever_field=whatever_value, defaults={'whatever_field' : whatever_value}), which will get or create a new article object using the supplied values and tell you whether or not it created a new object. Reference: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the answer I'm looking for is:

```
article = super(ArticleForm, self).save(commit=False)
```