# Django - How best to handle ValidationErrors after form.save(commit=False)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

This is a fragment of my code from a view:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        try:
            instance.account = request.account
            instance.full_clean()
        except ValidationError, e:
            # Do something with the errors here... I certainly don't want to do this 180 times.
```

This is an utter mess. Who would want to handle validation errors manually in every view. If you're not modifying the instance after `save(commit=False)`, you don't have to worry about this, but what about in my case where every model has a foreign key to `account` which is set behind the scenes and hidden from the user?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `form` is a `ModelForm` due to the tag on the question.

Since [`ModelForm` performs model validation when you call `is_valid()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-is-valid-method-and-errors), it should be sufficient to ensure the model instance it will be validating already contains any behind the scenes changes you want to make before you call `is_valid()`.

You could do that by modifying `form.instance` with your changes before you call `is_valid()`.

A more generic solution to make these kinds of change within the form itself would be:

```
class PresetAttrsModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        preset_attrs = kwargs.pop('preset_attrs', None)
        # Sets up self.instance, among other things
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if preset_attrs:
            for attr, value in preset_attrs.items():
                setattr(self.instance, attr, value)

class MyModelForm(PresetAttrsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

form = MyModelForm(preset_attrs={'account': request.account})
```

Comment: @insin +1 Thanks! I previously thought you could only access the instance after you called `instance = save(commit=False)`. I have **one more question for you though**: If I'm adding attributes manually, it means that I'm likely not including them in the form (even as hidden because of security). In this case, Django doesn't validate those fields with `is_valid()` because they're "excluded". How can I include them in the validation processes even if they're "excluded" so that I don't have to manually catch errors and use `form._update_errors()`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure understanding your problem correctly, but if you want to "centralize" the validation of your data in the form you can overwrite the clean() method of the form:

[django docs - overwrite clean method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

In order to alter data of the object based on the data passed in the form you could overwrite the form.save method:

[SOF discussion - overwrite save method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817284/overriding-the-save-method-in-django-modelform)