# Modifying a model object using custom field values from ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm building an application on Django 1.5 that stores location data with PostGIS.  For the prototype, the form to create a new location record requires that the user enter the latitude and longitude coordinates (I assumed this would be the easiest setup to code).

I've created a `ModelForm` like so:

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
  # Custom fields to accept lat/long coords from user.
  latitude  = forms.FloatField(min_value=-90, max_value=90)
  longitude = forms.FloatField(min_value=-180, max_value=180)

  class Meta:
    model   = Location
    fields  = ("name", "latitude", "longitude", "comments",)
```

So far, so good.  However, the `Location` model doesn't have `latitude` nor `longitude` fields.  Instead, it uses a `PointField` to store the location's coordinates:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  comments = models.TextField(null=True)

  # Store location coordinates
  coords = models.PointField(srid=4326)

  objects = models.GeoManager()
```

What I'm looking for is where to inject the code that will take values for the `latitude` and `longitude` inputs and store them as a `Point` object in the `Location`'s `coords` field once the user submits the form with valid values.

E.g., I'm looking for the Django equivalent of Symfony 1.4's `sfFormDoctrine::doUpdateObject()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some guidance from [stummjr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283493/212218) and poking around in `django.forms.BaseModelForm`, I believe I have found the solution:

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
  ...

  def save(self, commit=True):
    self.instance.coords = Point(self.cleaned_data["longitude"], self.cleaned_data["latitude"])
    return super(LocationForm, self).save(commit)
```

Comment: Nice, better than my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could [override the save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) in `Location` model.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comments = models.TextField(null=True)

    # Store location coordinates
    coords = models.PointField(srid=4326)

    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.coords =  ... # extract the coords here passed in through kwargs['latitude'] and kwargs['longitude']
        # don't forget to call the save method from superclass (models.Model)
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Supposing you have this view to process the form:

```
  def some_view(request):
      lat = request.POST.get('latitude')
      longit = request.POST.get('longitude')
      ...
      model.save(latitude=lat, longitude=longit)
```

Another option would be to [override the save method in your ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/817364/1084647).

Answer (score 0):

> Overide Form clean method to set coords

```
    def clean(self):
        lat = self.data.get("Longitude")
        long = self.data.get("Latitude")
        p = Point(long,lat,srid=4326)
        self.cleaned_data["coords"] = p
        super(LocationForm, self).clean()
```