# How can I save data in two different models from one form django?

Tags: django, forms, models

I have a situation where I have a form with 8 fields.

1. Two of which (First Name and Last Name) will go to the User model of
   django
2. The remaining six will go to the UserProfile model of my application

Now keeping in mind that I have a single form on the page. How can I use the UpdateView of django to update two different models coupled to a single form?

Comment: yo can overridin the save method . take a look at [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817284/overriding-the-save-method-in-django-modelform

Comment: You could have just created UserProfile such that it extended User.